# Width definida em css aparece como undefined para o Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, div

O problema é o seguinte:

1-Criei uma div e defini seus estilo pela classe dela, no css. Inclusive a width.

2- No javascript eu tento buscar pra alterar o valor dessa width, via "minhaDiv.style.width", mas não vem nada, ela parece estar undefined.

3-O meu script está escrito no body, depois do css.

4-Eu busco o elemento div no javascript via parâmetro de função de mouse over constante nela:

```
 <div id="Barra1" class="animacao" onmouseover="increaseBar(this)" 
    onmouseout="decreaseBar(this)" style="background-color: royalblue;">
    </div>
```

E o meu css:

```
<style>
    .animacao {
        border-bottom: 10px;
        border-top: 10px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 10px;
    }

</style>
```

E o javascript onde estou tentando alterar a width, e ela vem undefined:

```
<script>
    const initial = 10
    const end = innerWidth
    const step = 5

    function increaseBar(elem){

        const newBegining = elem.style.width+step

       //Nessa console.log abaixo, só aparece o meu texto e nenhum valor do lado 
       console.log("Largura no css: "+elem.style.width)

        if (newBegining < end){
            elem.style.width = newBegining
            setTimeout(() => increaseBar(elem), 1000)
        } 
    }

</script>
```

OBS: A div está vindo corretamente pelo parâmetro. Se eu dou um console.log no parâmetro "elem", aparece o html da minha div na console. Então, esse não é o problema.

Agora, não faço ideia do que seja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elem.style.width` retorna a largura definida por javascript.

ex:

```
function increaseBar(elem){

   elem.style.width = '150px';

   // já aparece 150px
   console.log("Largura no css: "+elem.style.width)
}
```

Pode usar:

- `clientWidth` é o interior do elemento, inclui o padding mas exclui bordas e scrollbar
- `offsetWidth` inclui padding bordas e scrollbar

Comment: Então, pra obter o width da div eu uso o elem.clientWidth ou elem.offsetWidth. Mas pra alterar a div, eu continuo atribuindo o novo valor pra elem.style.width?

Answer (score 1):

Use "**offsetWidth**" para acessar o valor que está no estilo CSS:

** observação para os ";" no código e a concatenação de "**px**" em:

```
elem.style.width = newBegining + 'px';
```

```js
const initial = 10;
const end = innerWidth;
const step = 5;

function increaseBar(elem){
    const newBegining = elem.offsetWidth + step;

   //Nessa console.log abaixo, só aparece o meu texto e nenhum valor do lado 
   console.log("Largura no css: "+ newBegining);

    if (newBegining < end){
        elem.style.width = newBegining + 'px';

    } 
}
```

```css
    .animacao {
        border-bottom: 10px;
        border-top: 10px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 10px;
        background-color: royalblue;
    }
```

```html
<div id="Barra1" class="animacao" onmouseover="increaseBar(this)"></div>
```